# Lambda Calculus Identity Function

Tags: computer-science, lambda-calculus

Dr. Benjamin Pierce's "Types and Programming Languages" mentions the *identify function* on page 55:

$id = \lambda x.x$;

I understand the identity function from usage in Haskell:

```
id' :: a -> a
id' x = x
```

It accepts a single argument and returns it.

But, what does $\lambda x.x$ mean in the above `id` function's right-hand side? Please break down each component of the function.

Example, in the Haskell `id'`, `id'` is the function's name. `a` is the input type and `a` is the output type. The `x` represents the input argument value and, consequently, the output value.

Comment: In haskel the equivalent function would be.  (\ x -> x) as lambda functions don't have names.

Answer (score 5):

Let's try to break down the syntax of `λx. x` into pieces:

- `λ` means that you are dealing with an abstraction (it is a fancy word for function in programming sense). It doesn't mean anything and it is there just for parsing purposes. See [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/55917/what-does-the-lambda-in-lambda-calculus-stand-for) if you are curious why  this particular letter was chosen.
- the first `x` occurrence -- it is called *binding* occurrence -- is a formal parameter name, just like Haskell's version first `x` after `id`.
- `.` is a separator between the formal parameter name and the abstraction's body. It's there for parsing only.
- the second occurrence of `x` constitutes the abstraction's body, which is like a Haskell function's body.

A couple comments:

- $id = \lambda x. x$ is *not* a piece of $\lambda$-calculus syntax, because it doesn't have `=`. So if you see something like `id y` you need to do "macro-expansion" of `id` to get a valid $\lambda$-term.
- `λx. x` is usually not a valid $\lambda$-term as well. It is syntactic sugar for `(λx. x)`. It is customary to get rid of the top-level parentheses and to drop some more parentheses while introducing the rules that prevent ambiguity.